# Another bootcamp partition restoration issue

Tags: disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I just removed Bootcamp from my 1TB Fusion drive, using Bootcamp Assistant. The process failed due to a disk error. After running First Aid as directed, Bootcamp Assistant no longer offers the option to remove the partition, but I have not managed to reclaim the space previously used for Windows.

Attached is my `diskutil list` output:

[image: screenshot of diskutil ouput]

I have two 'Macintosh HD' entries: would it be safe and appropriate to remove disk2s5?
Or should I take a different action to reclaim the old partition?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the command `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 0`?

Comment: @DavidAnderson No, I am unclear what the the different entries are and am wary of damaging anything, though I have made a backup. Would that expand the disk to occupy the remaining space?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I tried expanding disk1s2. Here's the last part of the report:


`Growing APFS Physical Store disk1s2 from 743,876,960,256 to 999,995,129,856 bytes
Modifying partition map
Growing APFS data structures
APFS Container Resize error code is 49180
A problem occurred; undoing all changes
Modifying partition map
Error: -69606: A problem occurred while resizing APFS Container structures
`

Comment: It seems that I am doomed to join the legions who tried to remove Bootcamp and ending up losing storage capacity down the black hole of disk space.